# Change default port 5672 for WSO2-API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

We already have Active MQ running on the server. As a result we are getting port conflict when running WSO2. Where can we change the port to avoid this conflict.

So far we have done the following:
1. Searched for references for port 5672 under /repository/conf and changed 5672 to 5673. Files changed included broker and jndi.

Looks like the conflict is resolved but some services are still trying to connect to port 5672. I have not been able to find where to change this.

```
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,342]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent WSO2 Message Broker is started.
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,374]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : Siddhi-JMS-Consumer initialized
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,379]  INFO - JMSTransportHandler Starting jms topic consumer thread...
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,800]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,811]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8280
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,815]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2017-02-03 08:37:36,825]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8243
[2017-02-03 08:37:37,669]  INFO - AMQConnection Unable to connect to broker at tcp://172.17.51.124:5672
org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:130)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:631)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:628)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:628)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:409)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener.checkJMSConnection(JMSListener.java:137)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener.start(JMSListener.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener.run(JMSListener.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:486)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener.checkJMSConnection(JMSListener.java:137)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener.start(JMSListener.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSListener.run(JMSListener.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
        at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:130)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:631)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:628)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:628)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:409)
        ... 7 more
[2017-02-03 08:37:37,750] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2017-02-03 08:37:37,756] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
[2017-02-03 08:37:39,373]  INFO - CarbonEventManagementService Starting polling event receivers
[2017-02-03 08:37:43,411]  INFO - ThriftDataReceiver Thrift Server started at 0.0.0.0
[2017-02-03 08:37:43,451]  INFO - ThriftDataReceiver Thrift SSL port : 7711
[2017-02-03 08:37:43,468]  INFO - ThriftDataReceiver Thrift port : 7611
```

Comment: You need to change the port in api-manager.xml as well. Same issue is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/41535384/3176125

Answer (score 2):

We resolved this by using port offsets. No need to manually change ports. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the offset parameter in your `<API-M-HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file, like:

```
[server]
offset=<offset_value>
```

Source: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-default-ports-with-offset/#changing-the-default-api-m-ports